# For a Glue job in a Glue workflow - given the Glue run id, how to access Glue Workflow runid?

Tags: python, aws-cli, aws-glue, aws-glue-workflow

An AWS Glue Workflow has multiple AWS Glue Jobs chained.

How do I get the workflow ID for a given AWS Glue Job run id?

I'm not able to locate an api in the aws-cli.

Note that I am trying to analyze job run metrics using an external Python code.

Comment: Have you tried accessing it using the job name from your glue job inside your workflow ?

Comment: In my scenario - I am trying to analyze job execution using a Python code outside of glue. So my starting point in Glue Job run id.

Comment: you cannot directly get the workflow run id but you can do https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.get_workflow_runs then filter for the job run id in this response . If you don't have workflow name then do batch_get_workflows pass all workflows you have then look for the job run id from this response

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy by the way batch_get_workflows requires you to know the names of the workflows. The way I think you can achieve this is use the `get_workflow`  then filter for the last run i.e `RunId`. Then use the `RunId` to visualize the run using `get_workflow_run` and make sure you include graph so you can see all the nodes and the run ids: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.get_workflow_run

Comment: @Eman that is true in case of one workflow but what if they don't know which workflow to query. In that case you need to get all work flow responses then filter for job run ids.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to get the runID

```
import boto3
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
glue_client = boto3.client("glue")
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME','WORKFLOW_NAME', 'WORKFLOW_RUN_ID'])
runID = args['WORKFLOW_RUN_ID']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom function like this built on the top of `boto3` library:

```
def get_wid_from_jid(jid: str) -> str:
    client = boto3.client('glue', region_name='us-east-1')
    response = client.list_workflows()

    jid_to_wid = {}
    for workflow in response.get('Workflows', []):
        response2 = client.get_workflow_runs(Name=workflow, IncludeGraph=True)

        for run in response2.get('Runs', []):
            wid = run.get('WorkflowRunId')
            for node in run.get('Graph', {'Nodes': []}).get('Nodes', []):
                for job in node.get('JobDetails', {'JobRuns': []}).get('JobRuns', []):
                    jid2 = job.get('Id')

                    if wid and jid2:
                        jid_to_wid[jid2] = wid

    return jid_to_wid.get(jid, 'Error: Glue Job Run ID unknown.')
```

And you can run this function as below examples:

```
print(get_wid_from_jid('TestingFailScenarioHere'))
# Output:
# Error: Glue Job Run ID unknown.

print(get_wid_from_jid('jr_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'))
# Output:
# wr_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```